# Is it improper to use fs.readFile() to read a file created by fs.createWriteStream()?

Tags: node.js, stream

node version: v12.16.1
os: windows 7

Recently I try to use fs.readFile() to access a log file created by fs.createWriteStream(), but only get the first line of it. But when I create a test file with the same content and use fs.readFile() to get it, it works just fine. Is it just because of the first file is created by fs.createWriteStream()?
I also run some tests about it:

```
//create a writeable stream
const fs = require('fs');
let output = fs.createWriteStream('./output.txt');

output.write('c1:1');
output.write('c1:2');
output.write('default:1');

//read the file synchronously
let read = fs.readFileSync('./output.txt','utf8');
console.log(`read the output file synchronously: \n${read}`);

//read the test file synchronously
let readTest = fs.readFileSync('./test.txt','utf8');
console.log(`read the test file synchronously: \n${readTest}`);

//read the file asynchronously
let readAsync = fs.readFile('./output.txt','utf8',(err,data)=>{
    console.log(`read the file asynchronously: \n${data}`);
});

//read the test file asynchronously
let readTestAsync = fs.readFile('./test.txt','utf8',(err,data)=>{
    console.log(`read the test file asynchronously: \n${data}`);
});

//read the file with fs.createReadStream
let stream = fs.createReadStream('./output.txt','utf8');

let readWithStream = "";

stream.on('data',(data)=>{
    readWithStream += data;
});

stream.on('end',(data)=>{
    console.log(`read the file with fs.createReadStream : \n${readWithStream}`);
});


//read the test file with fs.createReadStream
let streamTest = fs.createReadStream('./test.txt','utf8');

let readTestWithStream = "";

streamTest.on('data',(data)=>{
    readTestWithStream += data;
});

streamTest.on('end',(data)=>{
    console.log(`read the test file with fs.createReadStream : \n${readTestWithStream}`);
});
```

Here's the result:

[image: results in console]

Comment: The writestream may do its own buffering to more efficiently write to the disk.  You cannot guarantee that everything has been written to the disk from the stream until you either cause the stream to flush its writes (and wait for the flush to finish) or until you close the stream (and wait for the close to be done).

Comment: @jfriend00 After I add output.end() to my code and wrap all the test code into a callback function used by a setTimeout() with 5s delay, it works out. Thanks my friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment: The writestream may do its own buffering to more efficiently write to the disk. You cannot guarantee that everything has been written to the disk from the stream until you either cause the stream to flush its writes (and wait for the flush to finish) or until you close the stream (and wait for the close to be done).

Your timeout solution is a bit of a hack and not really the way you should be doing things.  You should really be listening for when the stream is actually done (event driven) rather than just picking a timeout time.

You can use an event handler like this:

```
output.on('close', readAfter);
```

to do that.  In this example, either the `close` or the `finish` event would work fine as both occur after the data has been flushed to the underlying operating system.  The `close` event occurs slightly later in the cycle, when the actual OS file resource has been confirmed to be closed which seems like the safest option to me.

Here's your whole block of code with that inserted and the `setTimeout()` removed.

```
//create a writeable stream for our Console instance as stdout
const fs = require('fs');
let output = fs.createWriteStream('./output.txt');

output.write('c1:1\n');
output.write('c1:2\n');
output.write('default:1\n');

// register an event handler for when the stream is closed and all data has been flushed to disk
output.on('close', readAfter);

output.end(); //close the writable stream

function readAfter(){
    //read the file synchronously
    let read = fs.readFileSync('./output.txt','utf8');
    console.log(`read the output file synchronously: \n${read}`);

    //read the test file synchronously
    let readTest = fs.readFileSync('./test.txt','utf8');
    console.log(`read the test file synchronously: \n${readTest}`);

    //read the file asynchronously
    let readAsync = fs.readFile('./output.txt','utf8',(err,data)=>{
        console.log(`read the file asynchronously: \n${data}`);
    });

    //read the test file asynchronously
    let readTestAsync = fs.readFile('./test.txt','utf8',(err,data)=>{
        console.log(`read the test file asynchronously: \n${data}`);
    });

    //read the file with fs.createReadStream
    let stream = fs.createReadStream('./output.txt','utf8');

    let readWithStream = "";

    stream.on('data',(data)=>{
        readWithStream += data;
    });

    stream.on('end',(data)=>{
        console.log(`read the file with fs.createReadStream : \n${readWithStream}`);
    });


    //read the test file with fs.createReadStream
    let streamTest = fs.createReadStream('./test.txt','utf8');

    let readTestWithStream = "";

    streamTest.on('data',(data)=>{
        readTestWithStream += data;
    });

    streamTest.on('end',(data)=>{
        console.log(`read the test file with fs.createReadStream : \n${readTestWithStream}`);
    });
};
```

Comment: My solution may work but is still a potential bug. Using events in the same work has no problem like that and is more efficient. The beauty of event-driven asynchronous programming. I get it.